# Changing order of summation in a probability generating function

Tags: probability-theory, summation, generating-functions, proof-explanation

Let $G(s)$ to be the generating function  of $X$ which takes non-negative integer values. I want to express $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^n P(x \leq n),$$
in terms of $G(s)$. We have that 
$$F(x) = P(x \leq n) = \sum_{k \leq n} f(x=k),$$
where $f$ is the mass function and $F$ is the distribution. Then,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^n P(x \leq n) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^n \left[ \sum_{k \leq n} f(x=k)\right] = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^{n-k} \left[ \sum_{k \leq n} f(x=k)s^k\right].$$
We now proceed to change the summation to get:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}s^n P(x \leq n) = \sum_{k =0}^{\infty}s^kf(x=k)\left[\sum_{n \geq k} s^{n-k}\right] = \sum_{n \geq k} s^{n-k}G(s).$$
Is this the right approach? I am not sure if i am changing the order of summation correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach can work, but it looks like you got caught up summing over $n$.  We have \begin{align}
\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty P(x \leq n)s^n &= \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \sum\limits_{k = 0}^n f(x = k) s^n \\
&=\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty \sum\limits_{n = k}^\infty f(x = k)s^n \\
&=\sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty f(x = k)\frac{s^k}{1 - s} \\
&=\frac{G(s)}{1-s}.
\end{align}